# Python in Emacs (no modes, plain installation)

Tags: python, emacs

I'm trying to start the Python interpreter in Emacs 22.3.1. I have no modes installed (nor I'm planning at the moment). Emacs recognises the Python file, but I have this in the initial message:

```
Loading python (compiled; note, source file is newer)...
Loading easymenu...done
Loading python (compiled; note, source file is newer)...done
Loading vc-git...done
Loading comint...done
apply: Searching for program: no such file or directory, python
```

The .emacs file has:

```
(custom-set-variables
'(python-python-command "python")
  )
```

I tried editing `defcustom python-python-command "python"` in `python.el` to set "python" to "c:\python32\python.exe", but no luck.

Pythonpath is set in Windows path.

Comment: Does running `python` work in `cmd`?

Comment: Surprisingly - no. I must investigate why...

Comment: It works now. I had an error in `path`. But now Emacs freezes.

Comment: Did you mean to say Emacs 22.3.1? That would be quite old. If so you should consider upgrading.

Comment: Could you edit your question to reflect your current state?

Comment: I'm not sure if I have to, it works now! It was entirely my mistake, 2 mistakes actually. 1) Invalid characters (space) in Windows `path` and 2) outdated Emacs version. It works out of the box. Thank for the help. How do I close question / add points?

Comment: You may as well add your own answer, and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer has two parts. The first thing that was wrong was the extra space character in Windows path settings. This caused Emacs not to fail while calling python.

The second part was Emacs freezing. Updating to the newest version solved the problem.

Thanks everyone for their comments!